# Graphs in Lucee

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I see an error using CFCHART with Lucee. Same code works in CF. But in Lucee it try to refer to a file graph.cfm in a folder lucee.

```
mytestserver.com/lucee/graph.cfm?img=026f01d7b8c85b891a9c35c102623747&type=png
```

Do I need to create any mapping? Should this mapping be in Lucee admin or in IIS?

Comment: So what is behind `graph.cfm`?

Comment: @JamesAMohler Not sure. This is not a code file. So I guess, it could be Lucee's implementation of graph. Actually that is what I am trying to understand what this graph.cfm is.

Comment: Are you sure `graph.cfm` is built into Lucee?

Comment: I think so. I have identical code running on CF2016. There is no request from that environment to lucee/graph.cfm.

Comment: Content of `graph.cfm` is: `<cfcontent file="#GetTempDirectory()#/graph/#listLast(url.img,'/\#server.separator.file#')#" type="image/#url.type#"><cfsetting showdebugoutput="no">`

Comment: My guess is that your Lucee context is not reachable. The physical path would be `/lucee/context/graph.cfm`. Can you access the regular Lucee web/server admin context?

Answer (score 2):

**The short answer is:** No, you don't need to add any additional mapping in IIS, nor in Lucee or Tomcat.

I've seen this question here for too long, so I'm placing an answer here to shed some light into Lucee's graph.cfm.

Some tags in CFML need to create additional image files to later embbed them as an inline HTML element into the reendered output altogether. Examples for such file creation are `<cfimage type="captcha" ...>` or like you have already noted in your issue, `<cfchart>`.

For such functionality Lucee needs to create these files temporarily somewhere and also make them publicly available. To achive this for cfimage/cfchart, Lucee creates the files in the web context folder of your webroot (which typically is located at `path-to-your-webroot\WEB-INF\lucee\temp\graph` ) and embbed them inline with a link to graph.cfm. The template graph.cfm just reads the temporary file from that folder, and delivers it in realtime to your application.

If you want to take a look into Lucees original graph.cfm, we can take a peek thanks to OpenSource:
[source of Lucees graph.cfm at github](https://github.com/lucee/Lucee/blob/6.0/core/src/main/cfml/context/graph.cfm)

In order to make the files and the template graph.cfm temporarily publicly available, which by the way sits behind the WEB-INF folder ( which is also hidden/blocked by default in Tomcat for securtiy reasons), Lucee MUST have a virtual mapping. But you don't need to set it up, because these are already set up by default. You can see this in the image below taken from the "Mapping"-section of Lucee Administrator:

[image]

Because graph.cfm is a .cfm file, IIS will redirect the request directly through the implemented CFML connector ( probably Boncode Connector ) per AJP to Tomcat. Thus you don't need to set any mapping in IIS neither.

Because you have not submitted any additonal error information, such as http error codes or stack traces, I don't have any clue of what might be the cause of your error. It may also be some incompability issue which might be addressed if you submit it to the Lucee core team.

Another possibility is that many installation guides advise you to lock down  the "/lucee/" path with IIS URL Rewrite Module, because this is also the path  where the Lucee Administrator sits behind. If so, you can change the setting in IIS Rewrite Rule and adapt the rule in such a manner, that it would not block the graph.cfm.

It's also important to note that many of these cftags are implemented as Lucee extensions (.lex files). These are not necessarily pre-shipped or pre-installed in Lucee, but you may install it within Lucee Administrator or get them from Lucees Download site and upload it through your Lucee Administrator in the "Extension" section.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this too. Issue being though the the default mapping still don't navigate to "graph.cfm" so we've added an IIS virtual mapping instead.